# populate gridview with search boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Okay all of us has at some point done window shopping for a car or a house! The interface we kinda used there I want to create! 3 dropdownlists or textboxes where the user can insert info which will be used to filter the search

[image]

Now problem is, I've search the web and found SOME help/code, but somehow it quite doesn't work. Beacause what I need, is for when the page loads, all the data should be displayed in a gridview (or any other view) and then when the user has selected/entered his/her info and clicks search, the view must change according to there search

I tried using the same code I used to register a student

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strcon = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VC_temps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Search_student", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("Course", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("Availability", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("JobSkill", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
    com.Parameters.Add(p1);
    com.Parameters.Add(p2);
    com.Parameters.Add(p3);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (rd.HasRows)
    {
           GridView1.DataSource = rd;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

with the following Stored-procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Search_student
(
@Course         varchar(30),
@Availability   varchar(50),
@JobSkill       varchar(50)
)
AS
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE Course = @Course OR Availability = @Availability OR JobSkill=@JobSkill
```

Can someone please help me finding the right code/solution to make this do what I want? I think this will help a lot of future coders because I couldn't find anything that matches what I want... Maybe I don't know where to look, but what I realized is there's to many variables involved in searching for something like this.

Comment: Hey please fill datasource of GridView1 with rd.

Answer (score 0):

Change Store procedure as follow, this shoul solve your problem...As you are using multiple parameters to search always use following way to write search query...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Search_student 
(
 @Course         varchar(30),
 @Availability   varchar(50),
 @JobSkill       varchar(50)
 )
AS
Begin
    SELECT * FROM Student 
    WHERE  Course =isnull(@Course,Course) 
    and Availability =isnull(@Availability,Availability)
    and JobSkill=isnull(@JobSkill,JobSkill)    
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of

```
   if (rd.HasRows)
    {
          rd.Read();
          GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Please use

```
   if (rd.HasRows)
   {
         GridView1.DataSource=rd;
         GridView1.DataBind();
   }
```